# mvc2 migration issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i migrate my mvc1 project to mvc2.

my jquery json result function does not work anymore. have any idea ?

aspx

```
$.getJSON('Customer/GetWarningList/0', function(jsonResult) {
                    $.each(jsonResult, function(i, val) {
                        $('#LastUpdates').prepend(jsonResult[i].Url);
                    });

                });
```

controller

```
public JsonResult GetWarningList(string id)
        {
            List<WarningList> OldBck = new List<WarningList>();

            return this.Json(OldBck);

        }
```

Comment: Do you get an exception?  What do you see in Firebug/Fiddler?  More information plz...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has been a change to JsonResult in MVC 2 and therefore it will no longer work with HTTP GET to avoid Json hijacking.

So you have two options

```
a. return your results via HTTP Post 

or 

b. the JsonRequestBehavior property to JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
```

There is an interesting article on how to modify [here](http://www.davidhayden.me/2009/11/jsonresult-and-jsonrequestbehavior-in-aspnet-mvc-2.html).

```
or (more elegant)

c. return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```